# Application based on Visual C++ distribution CefSharp browser launched only with admin security group

Tags: visual-c++, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Application based on Visual C++ distribution CefSharp browser launched  only with admin security group.
otherwise we get the following error:
"System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.
File name: 'CefSharp.Core.dll'
important VC++ distribution is installed. User of admin security group can launch application and CefSharp browser successfully.
Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue ?

OS - Window Server 2016

Comment: As a workaround you can try and bin deploy vc++ with your application.

Comment: We took CefSharp.MinimalExample-master copy it to our server win 2016.

Comment: We took CefSharp.MinimalExample-master copy it to our server win 2016. Uninstall VC++ distribution. launch  CefSharp.MinimalExample-master and it crashed es expected. Than we copied files from Microsoft.VC140.CRT:concrt140.dll,msvcp140.dll,vccorlib140.dll,vcruntime140.dll. The  CefSharp.MinimalExample-master worked. We deed same procedure on client but with no success. Any idea ?

Comment: You'll likely also need the Universal CRT dlls

Comment: We added the Universal CRT dlls but still we get same exception of access denied Cefsharp.core.dll. Any more ideas?

Comment: I vaguely remember a similar issue and the users needed to be added to a specific group, I just don't remember the exact details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,issue resolved.We ask Citrix server admin to install Chrome browser and than it turns out that Chrome is not launching by user that is not in admin group.
file c:\windows\system32\dbghelp.dll was missing permissions.
A policy was modifying permissions on that file.
once permission granted CefSharp browser launched with out admin privileges.